# want to fade and slide using jquery

Tags: jquery, slide, fade

This jquery code is not working.

I want to fade content section and slide up images when i clicked the next or prev navigation.

But not want the all the slide fade.
All files are included.

Included files:
Jquery File
Bootstrap css
Bootstrap Js

I tried so many times.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#demo').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
    $('.carousel-item .content').fadeOut();
    $('img').slideUp();
  });

  $('#demo').bind('slid', function(e) {
    $('.carousel-item.active .content').fadeIn();
    $('img').sildeUp();
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.thumb {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: .8;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: -50px;
}

.thumb img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="demo" class="carousel " data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="content col-lg-6">
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
            survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
            publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/soap-bubble-1958650_960_720.jpg">
          <div class="thumb">
            <img src="http://www.tonibest.com/cdn/25/1992/629/download-free-youtube-logo_176010.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="content col-lg-6">
          <p>
            It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
            content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
            Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZljhs-8w_yC4ZDLRmE9jnqbnaohkHiyTpXcwcjVwy0vA2VpID">
          <div class="thumb">
            <img src="https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/assets/011/118/399/3eee3106ac240bd35e56017a75a49be0_original.png?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&w=700&fit=max&v=1462546261&auto=format&frame=1&q=92&s=b330aea947831fdfe3a4e1fe235147bb">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="content col-lg-6">
          <p>
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
            one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
            Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from
            a line in section 1.10.32.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/soap-bubble-1958650_960_720.jpg">
          <div class="thumb">
            <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/o5YGpoRPaflraEPTD1nOCOm8o2k=/0x0:2040x1360/1200x800/filters:focal(857x517:1183x843)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/60142401/acastro_180403_1777_youtube_0001.0.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Anyone help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `slid.bs.carousel` not only `slid` to avoid race condition add the actions to slide finished event only.

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5wer0hcq/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#demo').bind('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
    $('.carousel-item.active .content').fadeOut().delay(300).fadeIn(500);
    $('.carousel-item.active img').slideUp().delay(300).fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

Comment: it works! thanks....................... but the main problem is that, i want to slider up current image and also slide up next upcoming image like https://www.dreamhost.com/ slider find below the pricing table.

Comment: they use jQuery plugin `slick`